What is the minimal degree $d$ of a polynomial in $n$ variables vanishing at $N$ points
Let consider $N$ points in Euclidean space of dimension $n$, $\boldsymbol{r}_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then, consider a polynomial $P(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ of $n$ variables vanishing at those $N$ points: i.e. $P(\boldsymbol{r}_i) = 0$ for all $i \in \{1,\dots,N\}$. My question is: What is the minimum degree $d$ of the polynomial $P$ in general?

My atempt: For $n=2$ the Lagrange interpolation formula ensures that $d = N-1$, providing an explicit formula. But, what about the general case?
It seems that if the points are in a sufficiently general position, we could project each $\boldsymbol{r}_i$ onto an XY plane obtaining $\pi(\boldsymbol{r}_i) = (x_i,y_i)$, and obtaining a Lagrange interpolation polynomial Y=p(X) of degree $N-1$ passing through $(x_1,y_1), \dots, (x_n,y_n)$. Thus, the polynomial $P(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n) = X_2 - p(X_1)$ vanishes at all the points. But then it seems that there is no unique minimal degree polynomial (using another projection, we obtain a completely different polynomial).

For $n = 1$ and $N = 2$, you should be thinking of a parabola (having two real roots, so $\pm(x-a)(x-b)$ for distinct $a,b \in \Bbb{R}$).  Does a parabola have degree $N-1 = 2-1 = 1$?

You complain that the polynomial for higher $n$ might not be unique. But for $n=2$ there is also no unique polynomial. With Lagrange interpolation, you can find a polynomial equation $y = p(x)$ (if the $y_i$ are pairwise distinct), but you could equally well find a solution of the form $x = q(y)$.

Edit: It's simpler than I remembered, the bound coming from counting monomials is always achievable but it's an upper bound, not a lower bound. Namely:
There are ${d+n \choose n}$ monomials of degree $\le d$ in $n$ variables. If we evaluate all of those monomials on the points $r_i$ we get a ${d+n \choose n} \times N$ matrix (I can never remember which is which so to be clear $N$ is the number of columns), and at the smallest value of $d$ such that ${d+n \choose n} > N$ this matrix has more rows than columns so there must be some linear dependence among its rows. This is exactly a linear combination of monomials vanishing on all the points, so this value of $d$ always works.
For $n = 1$ this gives $d = N$ which corresponds to just taking $P(x) = \prod (x - r_i)$; this is clearly best possible if the $r_i$ are distinct.
As another example, for $n = 2, N = 9$ we get ${5 \choose 3} = 10 > 9$ so we can always find a cubic polynomial passing through $9$ points in the plane, which is classical (and shows up in the context of the Cayley-Bacharach theorem). In general we have the rough lower bound ${d+n \choose n} \ge \frac{d^n}{n!}$ which implies that we can always take $d = \lceil \sqrt[n]{n! N} \rceil$; this is really not best possible but shows the asymptotic growth if $n$ is fixed and $N \to \infty$.
To show that this value of $d$ is best possible we would have to show that the matrix above generically has linearly independent rows if ${d+n \choose n} \le N$. This would be some kind of generalization of the invertibility of the Vandermonde matrix; if it's true it's probably well-known.

Nice. The problem, and the logic in your answer immediately reminded me of Madhu Sudan's celebrated list decoding algorithm of Reed-Solomon codes (in the case $n=2$). There the problem to be solved is to find all the (univariate) polynomials, whose graphs (introducing the second variable) pass through at least a fixed number of given points of the affine plane (over a finite field in that case).
